# How can we center title of react-navigation header?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

React-navigation docs are still young, and reading through the issues is not working quite much for me (changes on each version) does anyone have a working method to center title in Android using `react-navigation` in React Native?

Comment: there may be some solution for this, but what I do in my projects I don't use header and tabs from react-navigation. For header I use custom header (******performance of react-navigation tabs isn't that great*********).

Comment: Theres a `titleStyle`props that can be used for styling. Did you try it out ?
Here's the [link](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/search?utf8=✓&q=titleStyle). Check the `StackNavigator.md`

Comment: I did, i am trying to set default props to all screens, it did not work :/

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Warning: react-navigation changes a lot, the way to do title align, already changed for like 2-3 times from my first answer of it.

If my answer doesn't work for you, please see other answers.

### Modified 2021/08/31:

In year of 2020, [headerLayoutPreset](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#stacknavigatorconfig) was also deprecated. The new way is via defaultNavigationOptions: (@ThatFrenchComputerGuy's answer helped me)

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
 }, 
 {
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
      title: 'Aligned Center',
      headerTitleAlign: 'center'
  }
});
```

### Modified 2019/03/12:

In year of 2018, after react-navigation v2 release (7 Apr 2018), for some reason `alignSelf` was not working anymore. Here it is the new working way, using [headerLayoutPreset](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#stacknavigatorconfig). from @HasanSH:

```
const HomeActivity_StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: {screen: Main},
}, {headerLayoutPreset: 'center'});
```

### Original Answer 2017/07/11:

Use [headerTitleStyle](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=headerTitleStyle):

```js
static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitleStyle: { alignSelf: 'center' },
    title: 'Center Title',
}
```

[image]

Comment: doesn't work for me!,I added  textAlign:"center",flex:1 in order to accomplish the job.

Comment: On iOS it was working just fine but not on Android. Adding the code made it work for both platforms. Thanks

Comment: Not work for me to. I added headerRight: <View style={{ padding: 6 }} /> and it's working for me

Comment: headerLayoutPreset is deprecation and was renamed to headerTitleAlign and moved to navigationOptions. It should be declared on defaultNavigationOptions to get same behavior

Comment: 2021 with your updated answer is really working, thank you very much!!

Comment: Thanks for keeping this updated. `headerTitleAlign` is what I needed to fix Android alignment issue. iOS seemed to default to center.

Answer (score 140):

As of 2021, you can use [headerTitleAlign](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/stack-navigator#headertitlealign).

Although *headerLayoutPreset* technically works, it should display a message informing that it is deprecated for **expo users**.
The implementation is as follows:

```js
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: HomeScreen,
 }, 
 {
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
      title: 'Centered',
      headerTitleAlign: 'center'
  }
})
```

**React-Navigation v5.x Update:**
As per @Ewan ' s rectification, if you are using React-Navigation v5.x, you cannot pass parameters to createStackNavigator(). Therefore, you should implement it as follows:

```js
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerTitleAlign: 'center'}}>
```

[image: Here is an image of it working]

Comment: I have rarely seen a stack-overflow thread, that contains so many duplicated AND wrong answers. This answer works, but it makes large header texts overflow header buttons on Android. All other answers are the same or simply to not work.

Answer (score 61):

To center the header title, we need to have flex header by add flex property.

```
navigationOptions: {
    title: "Title center",
    headerTitleStyle: { 
        textAlign:"center", 
        flex:1 
    },
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: headerTitleStyle: { alignSelf: 'center' , textAlign:"center",flex:1 }, Worked for me!

Answer (score 52):

For anyone searching in 2020, this is working for me:

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerTitleAlign: 'center'}}>
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headertitlealign

Comment: I had to add `headerTitleStyle: { textAlign: 'center' },` as well

Comment: Works for react-navigation v5.

Comment: Right (and only working) anwser for react-navigation >=v5 (see: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headertitlealign)

Comment: Thanks. It is working.

Comment: This should be the preferred answer as it seems to be the standard API for this.  Please upvote.

Answer (score 31):

The accepted answer only works for me if there isn't a back button present on the left-hand side. In that case, you need to set an empty View to the right-hand side to properly center it.

```js
static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitleStyle: { alignSelf: 'center' },
    title: 'Center Title',
    headerRight: (<View />)
}
```

Comment: This is what I do most often, but I find this is a work-around and should not be treated as a proper answer. I have upvoted it anyway, because it's handy.

Comment: I totally agree that it's a workaround and I wish it wasn't.  But I don't think there's a proper solution yet. Hopefully, it will be fixed soon.

Comment: I also added `flex: 1, textAlign: 'center',` to headerTitleStyle and `headerLeft: (<View/>),` AND worked

Comment: This works for me if I have a button on both sides.
`{headerTitleStyle: { alignSelf: 'center' },
    title: 'Center Title',
    headerLeft: (<Icon ... />),
    headerRight: (<View />)
}`

Answer (score 24):

The best way to do that is by implementing what is listed in the documentation:
Inside the `StackNavigatorConfig` assign an optional property, as follows:

```
createStackNavigator({
   { ... // your screens},
   { ...,
     headerLayoutPreset: 'center' // default is 'left'
   })
```

`headerLayoutPreset` - Specifies how to lay out the header components.

By doing this you don't have to mess up with the styling at all. And it would be applied to all the nested screens in that stack.

Check the [Source](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#stacknavigatorconfig)

Comment: it works and deals all cases with/without the back arrow

Comment: This is the most appropriate answer :)

Comment: But only for react-native < v5, else use Ewan's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60779193/1256697

Answer (score 10):

Insert and set the `headerTitleAlign` value in `defaultNavigationOptions`. Here is the examples:

```
const MainStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        ...

        defaultNavigationOptions: {
            headerTitleAlign: 'center',
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: react-navigation has updated and this is, currently, the correct way to do this.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html

Comment: Great!!... This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 9):

For React Navigation V6
Following is working fine for me:

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerTitleAlign: "center" }}>
// Put all of your screens here <Stack.Screen ... />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 8):

#### This worked for me :)

```
static navigationOptions = {
title: "SAMPLE",
headerTitleStyle: { flex: 1, textAlign: 'center'},
```

};

Answer (score 5):

if you're using `react-navigation v4`

```
const stack = createStackNavigator({
  screen1: {screen: Screen},
},{
  defaultNavigationOptions: {
    headerTitleAlign: 'left | center',
  }
});
```

Docs:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#headertitlealign

or if you're using `react-navigation v3`

```
const stack = createStackNavigator({
  screen1: {screen: Screen},
},{
  headerLayoutPreset: 'left | center',
});
```

Docs:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/3.x/stack-navigator.html

Answer (score 5):

I am using react navigation with below dev dependencies, with alignSelf and textAlign I was getting warnings [image]

```
  "dependencies": {
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.0",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.0.0",
"base64-js": "^1.3.1",
"lodash": "^4.17.15",
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
"react-native-base64": "0.0.2",
"react-native-ble-plx": "^1.1.1",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.6",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.2",
"react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-beta.2"
```

},

none of above option worked for me, then I tried property **headerTitleAlign: 'centre'** and it worked.

below is my component code

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Home"
              component={HomeScreen}
              options={{
                title: 'Track Down',
                headerTitleAlign: 'center',
              }}
            />

          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    };
```

Answer (score 5):

While I was facing the same thing but the solution is pretty easy.
I just added one line of code `headerTitleAlign: 'center',`

```js
function HomeNavigator() {
  return (
    <TabOneStack.Navigator>
      <TabOneStack.Screen
        name="HomeScreen"
        component={TabOneScreen}
        options={{
          headerRightContainerStyle: {
            marginRight: 20,
          },
          headerTitleAlign: 'center',     <-------- here
          headerTitle: () => (
            <Ionicons
              name={'logo-twitter'}
              color={Colors.light.tint}
              size={30}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </TabOneStack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
headerTitleStyle: {
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
               flex: 1
}
```

Answer (score 4):

for `@react-navigation/native@next`, I can confirm `{ headerTitleAlign: 'center' }` works for me on android. Example below:

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerTitleAlign: 'center' }}>
    <Stack.Screen name="Promo" component={PromoScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsNavigator} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 3):

Set react-navigation header title in the center. Using the headerTitleStyle CSS.

```
static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Home',
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerTitleStyle: {
            width: '90%',
            textAlign: 'center',
        },
    };
```

Comment: Please make this a full answer, not just a code answer with no explanation.

Answer (score 3):

```
navigationOptions:({navigation}) =>({
                    gesturesEnabled :false,

                    headerTitleStyle : {
                            color:"white",
                            fontFamily:"OpenSans",
                            alignSelf: 'center' ,
                            textAlign: 'center',
                            flex:1
                    },
                  }),
```

here . => `{flex:1 ,textAlign: 'center' and   alignSelf: 'center'}` works for me!

Answer (score 3):

You should add headerLayoutPreset: 'center' to your createeStackNavigator function.

This is the one true way:

```
const someStack = createStackNavigator({
ConfigurationScreen: ConfigurationScreen,
PreferencesScreen: PreferencesScreen},
{ headerLayoutPreset: 'center' });
```

Reference:
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/pull/4588

Answer (score 3):

On React Navigation v5 the only way I managed to center a View was to use it like this:

```
 <MainStack.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerTitleAlign: 'center',
  }}>

 ...

  <MainStack.Screen
    ...
    options={({navigation, route}) => ({
      headerTitle: () => <ViewButton />,
    ...
    })}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the year 2020, if anyone had a problem as I did, below piece of snippet worked for me.

```
<Stack.Screen options={({ route, navigation }) => ({
          title: "Register",
          headerTitleAlign: "center")
        })}
 />
```

Answer (score 3):

As per version 5.x of ReactNavigation, you can use option header attribute **headerTitleAlign** with value **center**. Here is example of the code:

```
<Stack.Screen name="ScreenRegister" component={ScreenRegister}
   options={{ 
       headerTitle: props => <LogoHeader {...props} />,
       headerTitleAlign: 'center'
    }} 
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [headerTitleContainerStyle](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#headertitlecontainerstyle)

```
static navigationOptions = {
  headerTitleStyle: { justifyContent: 'center' },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me on Android & iOS:

```
static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitleStyle: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    headerRight: (<View/>)
};
```

Answer (score 2):

As of 30th May 2020, you can't no more pass any parameters to `createStackNavigator()`.

To center your title, you have to use the following (with the `headerTitleAlign` property):

```
<Stack.Screen
    name="Centered"
    component={Centered}
    options={{
      title: 'Centered title',
      headerShown: true,
      headerTitleAlign:'center'
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

*This will definately work for android*

```
      headerTitleStyle:{
         flex: 1, textAlign: 'center'
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

headerTitleStyle: {
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
    flex: 1
}

Comment: This just repeat existing answers. New answers should add new information and new insights into the topic.

Answer (score 1):

add `headerTitleAlign: 'center'` in `navigationOptions`

example:

```js
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    headerTitle: (
      <Image
        style={{width: 100, height: 100}}
        resizeMode="contain"
        source={icons.logo}
      />
    ),
    headerTitleAlign: 'center',
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

In react navigation V5

```
<AuthStack.Screen
  name="SignupScreen"
  component={SignupScreen}
  options={{ title: "Sign Up", animationEnabled: false, headerTitleAlign: 'center', }}
/>
```

Comment: add options={{ title: "Sign Up", animationEnabled: false, headerTitleAlign: 'center'}}

Answer (score 1):

If the header has more than 1 item ie left , right , center as below :

```js
  <TabOneStack.Screen
        name="HomeScreen"
        component={TabOneScreen}
        options={{
          headerLeftContainerStyle: { marginLeft: 10 },
          headerRightContainerStyle: { marginRight: 10 },
          headerTitleContainerStyle: { backgroundColor: "yellow", alignItems: "center" },
          headerLeft: () => <ProfilePicture image="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1383042648550739968/fS6W0TvY_200x200.jpg" size={40} />,
          headerTitle: () => (<Ionicons name="logo-amazon" size={30}  />),
          headerRight: () => (<MaterialCommunityIcons name="star-four-points-outline" size={30} />)
        }}
      />
```

then adding `alignItems:center` to `headerTitleContainerStyle` will center the title component [image]

Answer (score 1):

just use ***options*** property additionally,

```
<Stack.Screen
      component={HomeScreen}
      name="Skin Cancer Prediction"
      options={{
          headerTitleAlign: "center",
      }}
/>
```

you're good to go

Answer (score 0):

headerTitleStyle :{textAlign: 'center', flex: 1}

worked for me

Comment: Please consider providing a little more context, and possibly an explanation about _why_ the code works.

Answer (score 0):

```
 headerTitleAlign: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
      },
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! To help other understand your solution, can you provide a quick description of why this code works?

Answer (score 0):

Working with **React Navigation v5** you can also use the following option:

**`headerTitleAlign:'center'`**

Like in the below example where I wanted to perfectly center the title.

```
<Stack.Screen
    name="Settings"
    component={SettingsScreen}
    options={{
      title: 'SMS Recipient Number',
      headerShown: true,
      headerTitleAlign:'center'
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply this works for me with latest version 16.9.0,

```
defaultNavigationOptions : {title: 'App', headerTitleAlign: 'center' }
```

Answer (score 0):

we can achieve this with

***headerTitleStyle :{
alignSelf:"center"
};***

Answer (score -3):

Make sure to check the issues before resulting to stack overflow, normally more helpful.[issue regarding your problem](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1443) But as himanshu said in comments you need to access the title style property to adjust the title how you want.

```js
static navigationOptions = {
    header: (navigation) => ({
      title: <Text style={{ 
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .9)', 
            fontWeight: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? '600' : '500',  
            fontSize: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 17 : 18, 
            alignSelf: 'center' 
         }}>Filters</Text>,
      right: <SearchButton />,
      left: <CancelButton />,
    })
  };
```

As shown in the issue, i presume you've already managed to find a solution as this was a while ago. But for anyone else coming across this issue it may be helpful.

Answer (score -4):

You can set the header title center for android in stack navigator of react navigation using this file change:

```
node_modules\react-navigation\src\views\Header.js
```

Change This Code In Header.js file:-

```js
title: {
bottom: 0,
left: TITLE_OFFSET,
right: TITLE_OFFSET,
top: 0,
position: 'absolute',
alignItems: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'center' : 'center',
},
```

Comment: don't modify files in node_modules!  the changes can be easily stomped, and if you use yarn, the next package you install will revert the change

Comment: what's the use of ternary operator when both ends have same value?