# How to use react-navigation to center headerTitle?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
Home: {
  screen: Home,
  headerTitleStyle: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
  }
```

HeaderTitleStyle is used for header style in code but does not take effect

Comment: Did you try `textAlign: 'center'` or even `justifyContent: 'center'`?

Comment: yes, These styles have been used but they have no effect

Comment: They should work like css..that's weird, there's some [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/544), [check them](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/253). There's also a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43326705/how-can-we-center-title-of-react-navigation-header). I'm not that experienced =/

Comment: thank you, let me have a see

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we center title of react-navigation header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43326705/how-can-we-center-title-of-react-navigation-header)

Answer (score 8):

I have encountered this issue on Android devices. After searching for a while, there were many suggestions to use `alignSelf: 'center'`. However it wasn't fixed with it. But I was able to fix it by `textAlign: 'center' and flex: 1`

You could specify the navigationOptions in your component:

`static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitleStyle: { textAlign: 'center', flex: 1 },
};`

**UPDATED:**
The best solution is to use `headerLayoutPreset: 'center'` in createStackNavigator()

`const MainStack = createStackNavigator({
    screen: YourScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Title'
    }
},
{
  headerLayoutPreset: 'center'
});`

I hope this should work:-)

Comment: Thank you,Did you use this method to take effect?

Comment: Yes, I have used it in my projects. This is the best solution I found for this issue.

Answer (score 5):

On the newer versions (2020) you should use (inside navigationOptions), this:
headerTitleAlign: 'center'
It should work! ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
static navigationOptions = {
    headTtle: () => (
        <View style={styles.headerWrapper}>
            <Text
                adjustsFontSizeToFit
                style={styles.headerText}>首页</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    headerWrapper: {
        flex: 1
    },
    headerText: {
        textAlign: 'center', // ok
        alignSelf: 'center', // ok
    }
});
```

In this way can be solved， it's work

Comment: Nice! I hope I could help

Comment: yes,sure, where are you from?， Can I add a contact method?