# React Navigation, how to hide the back button title?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using React Native to build an Android and iOS application. I'm using `react-navigation` to navigate between screens.

The problem is that the navigation on iOS is different from the one in Android (image below). I want both of them to be like on Android, so how can I hide the 'Search cars' from iOS?

[image]

I've set the navigation options as follows:

```
Screen.navigationOptions = () => {

    const title = 'Search location';

    return {
        headerTitleStyle: {
            fontSize: 18,
            color: styles.headerTitle.color,
            paddingTop: 5,
            height: 40
        },
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#fdfdfd'
        },
        title
    };
};
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45027059/1283345

Answer (score 10):

As of version 5, it is the option headerBackTitleVisible in screenOptions

Example of usage:

**1. In Navigator**

```
<Stack.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerBackTitleVisible: false
  }}
>
  <Stack.Screen name="route-name" component={ScreenComponent} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

**2. In Screen**

if you want only to hide in the single screen you can do this by setting the screenOptions on the screen component see below for example:

```
<Stack.Screen options={{headerBackTitleVisible: false}} name="route-name" component={ScreenComponent} />
```

**3. In Screen Navigation Options**

```
Screen.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
 headerTitle: 'Title',
 headerLeft: () =>
    <View>
      /* custom View here - back icon/back button text */
    </View
}
```

**4. Common in navigator for all the screens**

```
import { HeaderBackButton } from '@react-navigation/elements';

 <Stack.Navigator
            screenOptions={({ navigation }) => ({
                headerLeft: () => (
                    <HeaderBackButton
                        labelVisible={false}
                        tintColor={'#FFF'}
                        onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
                    />
                )
            })}>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `headerBackTitleVisible: false` to hide the back button title. It can be on a Screen's `options`, on a Navigator's `screenOptions`, or like in your case inside `Screen.navigationOptions`.

```js
Screen.navigationOptions = () => {

    const title = 'Search location';

    return {
        headerBackTitleVisible: false, // all you needed
        headerTitleStyle: {
            fontSize: 18,
            color: styles.headerTitle.color,
            paddingTop: 5,
            height: 40
        },
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#fdfdfd'
        },
        title
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

headerBackVisible:false

add in navigation options

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem as follows:

Import the useNavigation from '@react-navigation/native':

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

Import the Feather from '@expo/vector-icons':

```
import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons';
```

Create a variable receiving the useNavigation:

```
const navigation = useNavigation();
```

Inside the Stack.Screen, you add the option below, this way it replaces the default button for the 2 platforms (Android and iOS) with this new one that you are implementing:

```
  <Stack.Screen
    name="FinishOrder"
    component={FinishOrder}
    options={{
      title: 'Finishing',
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontSize: 25,
        color: '#FFF'
      },
      headerTitleAlign: 'center',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#1D1D2E'
      },
      headerLeft: () => (
        <Feather
          name='arrow-left'
          size={35}
          onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
          title="Voltar"
          color="#FF3F4B"
        />
      ),
    }} />
```

Result:

[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikrfD.png)

Answer (score -3):

headerBackTitle: false worked for me.

```
<Stack.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerBackTitle: false,
  }}
>
```